# Как пройтись циклом в словаре, чтобы получить только значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список, в нем словарь. Как правильно пройтись циклом, чтобы 
получить при выводе только значения `(animal, "2337 24", Берта)`?

```
 my_list = [
    {"type": "animals", "number": "2337 24", "name": "Берта"},
    {"type": "people", "number": "921-241", "name": "Ваня Пупкин"},
    {"type": "people", "number": "103126", "name": "Петя Пупкин"}
  ]
```

Comment: Если можно искать по `number` -  `[tuple(x.values()) for x in my_list if x['number'] == '2337 24']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = [
    {"type": "animals", "number": "2337 24", "name": "Берта"},
    {"type": "people", "number": "921-241", "name": "Ваня Пупкин"},
    {"type": "people", "number": "103126", "name": "Петя Пупкин"}
]
for element in my_list:
    for key in element.keys():
        print(element[key])
```

Comment: В Python не гарантируется, что при итерации ключи будут именно в том порядке, в котором они были заданы при инициализации словаря. Поэтому значения скорее всего будут выводиться не в том порядке, как в вопросе, а в каком-то другом. При тесте данного ответа у меня вывелось в порядке имя-число-тип.

Comment: если вас порядок ключей не интересует, то чтобы вывести значения в произвольном порядке: `for d in my_list: print(*d.values())`

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы вывести значения из словарей в выбранном порядке ключей, [можно `operator.itemgetter` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from operator import itemgetter

getvalues = itemgetter('type', 'number', 'name') 
for d in my_list:
    print(*getvalues(d))
```

Результат:

```
animals 2337 24 Берта
people 921-241 Ваня Пупкин
people 103126 Петя Пупкин
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [
    {"type": "animals", "number": "2337 24", "name": "Берта"},
    {"type": "people", "number": "921-241", "name": "Ваня Пупкин"},
    {"type": "people", "number": "103126", "name": "Петя Пупкин"}
]

# Т.к. у словарей в Python нет определенного порядка ключей, то нужно явно задать в каком порядке получать значения:
keys = ('type', 'number', 'name')

# Выводим тройки значений
for item in my_list:
    print(tuple(item[key] for key in keys))
# ('animals', '2337 24', 'Берта')
# ('people', '921-241', 'Ваня Пупкин')
# ('people', '103126', 'Петя Пупкин')

# Если не нужно выводить, а нужно сформировать список:
s = [tuple(item[key] for key in keys) for item in my_list]

# Просто вывести значения из словарей в "произвольном" порядке
# в моем случае выводит в порядке number - name - type, но на данный порядок полагаться нельзя
for item in my_list:
    print(tuple(item.values()))
# ('2337 24', 'Берта', 'animals')
# ('921-241', 'Ваня Пупкин', 'people')
# ('103126', 'Петя Пупкин', 'people')
```

Comment: можно заменить `tuple(item[key] for key in keys)` [на `itemgetter(keys)`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629757/23044)